# Why is systemd not configuring the VLANs' IPs correctly?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd, vlan

I am running an Archlinux machine and I want to get VLANs running. According to [Archluinx Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN) I have tried to configure.

What I want to achieve:
Network card `enp4s0` gets 2 IPv4 addresses `192.168.0.249` and `192.168.5.5` both `/24`. Additionally I want to create a virtual controller `vlan1` that is in VLAN with `id=1` with the IPv4 `192.168.4.5/24`.

I have a running configuration without the VLAN thing in my productive system. I tried to add the other parts to the configuration like the following:

```
# In /etc/systemd/network/lan.network
[Match]
MACAddress=<MAC of the physical interface>

[Address]
Address=192.168.0.249/24
[Address]
Address=192.168.5.5/24

[Route]
Gateway=192.168.5.1

[Network]
VLAN=vlan1 # <--- This line is new
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

I added also two more files in `/etc/systemd/network`:

```
# vlan1.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=vlan1
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=1
```

and

```
# vlan1.network
[Match]
Name=vlan1

[Network]
DHCP=no

[Address]
Address=192.168.4.5/24
```

When restarting the `systemd-networking` service (or rebooting) a `vlan1` interface gets created. However, the file `vlan1.network` seems to be ignored completely. The new interface gets the IPs copied from `enp4s0`. The `192.168.4.0/24` network is not assigned to any adapter. So I cannot reach any of these machines while having routes to the wrong devices.

Here is the output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:8d:5c:4e:53:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.249/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp4s0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.5.5/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global enp4s0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:8070:c1a0:7000:428d:5cff:fe4e:53cb/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
    valid_lft 413147sec preferred_lft 110747sec
    inet6 fe80::428d:5cff:fe4e:53cb/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.1.22.1 peer 10.1.22.2/32 scope global tun0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::106a:de17:dd6e:3f34/64 scope link stable-privacy 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.1.21.1 peer 10.1.21.2/32 scope global tun1
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7d1b:3f04:e82c:6a60/64 scope link stable-privacy 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.1.20.1 peer 10.1.20.2/32 scope global tun2
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::33ad:9ca3:121a:4360/64 scope link stable-privacy 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-281bb5420586: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:fb:44:85:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-281bb5420586
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:fbff:fe44:85f8/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br-4b99362f92cc: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:46:95:82:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-4b99362f92cc
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-57b5f61b2f20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:64:eb:e6:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-57b5f61b2f20
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:64ff:feeb:e64a/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: br-8487e108bf3a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b2:2d:b1:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-8487e108bf3a
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:b2ff:fe2d:b1cc/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:55:c5:93:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:55ff:fec5:93a9/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: vethf7a4cfe@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-281bb5420586 state UP group default 
    link/ether 7a:51:cf:e0:33:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::7851:cfff:fee0:33d3/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: vethe7356fb@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 1a:98:38:e8:3e:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::1898:38ff:fee8:3eb8/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: veth22fb0d5@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-8487e108bf3a state UP group default 
    link/ether ca:ec:ab:6f:02:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::c8ec:abff:fe6f:274/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: veth685a449@if18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-281bb5420586 state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:10:fa:61:78:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::ec10:faff:fe61:78a8/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: veth1000b45@if20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-57b5f61b2f20 state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:b4:13:46:79:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::ecb4:13ff:fe46:79c2/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: vethffd57b1@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-8487e108bf3a state UP group default 
    link/ether 5a:a3:01:3f:85:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::58a3:1ff:fe3f:851a/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: veth8051ebf@if24: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-281bb5420586 state UP group default 
    link/ether 86:17:70:25:44:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::8417:70ff:fe25:44d3/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: vethe305af6@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-57b5f61b2f20 state UP group default 
    link/ether 7e:a9:d3:b5:31:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::7ca9:d3ff:feb5:3114/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
29: veth7c4a3b4@if28: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-281bb5420586 state UP group default 
    link/ether 32:b2:a0:f3:8d:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 8
    inet6 fe80::30b2:a0ff:fef3:8dad/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: vlan1@enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:8d:5c:4e:53:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.249/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global vlan1
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.5.5/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global vlan1
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::428d:5cff:fe4e:53cb/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You see, the `vlan1` has the wrong IPs attached. The command `ip route` confirms this further:

```
default via 192.168.5.1 dev enp4s0 proto static 
default via 192.168.5.1 dev vlan1 proto static 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.21.2 dev tun1 
10.1.20.0/24 via 10.1.20.2 dev tun2 
10.1.20.2 dev tun2 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.20.1 
10.1.21.0/24 via 10.1.21.2 dev tun1 
10.1.21.2 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.21.1 
10.1.22.0/24 via 10.1.22.2 dev tun0 
10.1.22.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.22.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-8487e108bf3a proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-281bb5420586 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-57b5f61b2f20 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-4b99362f92cc proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.249 
192.168.0.0/24 dev vlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.249 
192.168.5.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.5.5 
192.168.5.0/24 dev vlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.5.5 
192.168.6.0/24 via 10.1.21.2 dev tun1
```

I tried it in a small virtual environment to avoid messing with the production machine, there the behavior is perfectly useful: The `vlan` interface gets **only** the configured IPs in the `*.network` file. The original routes are *not* copied over (which seems nasty at best).

In the logs of `systemd-networkd.service` the following lines appear after the restart:

```
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: veth7c4a3b4: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vethe305af6: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: veth8051ebf: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vethffd57b1: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: veth1000b45: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: veth685a449: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: veth22fb0d5: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vethe7356fb: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vethf7a4cfe: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: docker0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: br-8487e108bf3a: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: br-57b5f61b2f20: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: br-281bb5420586: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: tun2: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: tun1: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: tun0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: enp4s0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: Enumeration completed
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: netdev ready
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: Gained carrier
Feb 26 17:54:31 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: Could not bring up interface: Invalid argument
Feb 26 17:54:32 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: enp4s0: Configured
Feb 26 17:54:33 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 26 17:54:45 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: Configured
Feb 26 17:58:43 server-hh systemd-networkd[21461]: vlan1: Lost carrier
```

The error in the logs are 1:1 in the logs of the test system as well. This seems to be a bug regarding the logging output as far as I understood.

Maybe I am simply silly or overdue but I do not get the reason why this happens only in the production server and not in the test server. Do you have any suggestions where I can look further in order to get into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `MACAddress=` in [Match] section if the .network file contains `VLAN=`.

For details, see comments in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11921.

Comment: So, what should they do? Just leave out the ``MACAddress=`` line?  Leave out the entire ``[Match]`` section if it’s otherwise empty?

Comment: I solved it by adding `Type=!vlan` to the `MACAddress` match. This made it match correctly.

Comment: `Type=!vlan` works. Alternatively, `Type=ether` is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

For those running in a similar problem:

I had to rename the vlan interface to `enp4s0.1` instead of `vlan1`. I thought I could give any name I liked but this did not work as expected. I will maybe ask the developers of systemd but for now a workaround is found.